# Handling apollo graphql errors globally and render custom ErrorHandler component on error

Tags: react-redux, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Need to handle Apollo graphql errors globally in client side and render custom *ErrorHandler* component on error . So I used Apollo's **afterware** and **apollo-link-error**

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'


const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const logoutLink = onError(({ networkError }) => {
  if (networkError.statusCode === 401) {
    //need to dispatch a redux action so that ErrorHandler component renders
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: logoutLink.concat(httpLink),
});
```

My solution for this (which I guess, is not the correct approach)

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import ErrorHandler from '../utils/ErrorHandler';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const logoutLink = onError(({ networkError }) => {
  if (networkError.statusCode === 401) {
    const targetDiv = document.getElementById('serviceErrorHandler');       
    render(
       <ErrorHandler message={networkError.message}/>,
       targetDiv
    );
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: logoutLink.concat(httpLink),
});
```

Please suggest an approach for my scenario. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this same problem, one solution we went with was making a function that returns `onError` and take a parameter (the store):

```
const errorHandler = store => onError((errors) => {
  if (errors.networkError) {
    store.dispatch(createApolloErrorAction({
      message: GENERIC_ERROR_FETCHING_STRING,
    }));
  }
});
```

And use it in a wrapper functions to pass in the store:

```
let apolloClient = null;

export const createApolloClient = (reduxStore) => {
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();
  const link = errorHandler(reduxStore).concat(otherLink);

  apolloClient = new ApolloClient({ link });

  return apolloClient;
};
export const getApolloClient = () => apolloClient;
```